# setting specific columns as editable in kendo ui grid, with MVVM binding

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I am using the kendo ui web grid. I am trying to figure out how to make one column editable and another not editable. Teleriks documentation seem to only covers the case when you are declaring your own dataSource object. But I am using the MVVM declarative binding. So I don't explicitly create a dataource. And for this scenario I can only find documentation for setting the entire grid as editable (by setting the config of the kendoGrid initialization to `editable:true`), not how to selectively setting specific columns as editable/non-editable.

Can anyone help me out here?

(Telerik should really look over their their documentation, seems like all of the api doc and how-to's are focused on the less elegant programatical binding with datasource object, which leaves one clueless regarding how to accomplish the same thing with MVVM binding).

Answer (score 3):

You can either try and create [Template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnstemplate-string) column (column which you do not specify field just template) or you set the [editable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemamodel-objectkendodatamodel) option in your dataSource configuration to false.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "ProductID",
            fields: {
                 ProductID: {
                    //this field will not be editable (default value is true)
                    editable: false
                 }
           }
       }
   }
```

});

Comment: Your answer certainly works, thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't apply in my scenario. I don't create a kendo.data.DataSource explicitly. I subclass ObservalbeObject and create grid row elements via kendo.data.Model.define(). Here is a jsfiddle that illustrate my scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJeJ8/2/ So what I would like is for the "Random" column to be non-editabl